# How can I change the email associated with my Windows 10 account?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, windows-10, microsoft-account

I switched to Windows 10 but the email address I gave it was not the email address that I want associated with the account (the instructions were not clear). How do I change my account to be with another email address? And I do not want an alias, I want to move my Windows 10 account to another account.

Comment: Settings->Sign-in options.  Select switch to local account, then after you restart, connect the local account to the correct Microsoft Account.  If that does not answer your question you will need to better explain what your question is.

Comment: As of 2016, "Sign in with a local account instead" has moved to Settings -> Accounts -> Your Info. It is no longer under Settings -> Accounts -> Sign-in options, even though semantically it would belong there.

Answer (score 1):

For the last version of Windows 10, I've tried in many ways to dissociate my admin account with a bad Microsoft email account, but failed. Finally, I succeeded by **deletion/recreation** of the admin account, say **goodadmin**:

Before proceeding, please make a backup of personnal data for the admin user account **goodadmin**.

Following are detailed steps:

1. Log in as current administrator account, named **goodadmin**.
2. Settings/Accounts, add a new temporary admin account, named for instance **tempadmin**.
3. Log out from **goodadmin** session.
4. Log in with **tempadmin**/password.
5. Settings/Accounts, delete the old administrator account **goodadmin**. Danger, 
   *this will delete all data for **goodadmin** account, documents, music, downloads*...
6. Restart Computer and log in with **tempadmin**/password.
7. Settings/Accounts, create a new admin account named **goodadmin**, just as the original name used as you install your Windows 10.
8. Restart computer and log in with **goodadmin**/password.
9. Settings/Accounts, delete the administrator user account **tempadmin** temporary created.
10. Restart computer, log in with **goodadmin**/password.

You now restored your original system, without the bad email associated with **goodadmin** account.

With this method, I've gotten rid of the family security setting constraints for my good admin account, imposed to the bad email account of a child hours control.